# Return array from object if contains string jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, regex

I use regex to query all square brackets in string by this command:

```
var sizecolor = textvalue.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
```

I want to get a square bracket in object above if it contain "SPrice";

**Example:**
I have string like this:

```
"I have two square brackets are `[Apple = Red, Cool, Sweet]` and `[Check+SPrice = Cheap, Expensive, Comfortable]`"
```

How can I returns this `[Check+SPrice = Cheap, Expensive, Comfortable]` because it contains `SPrice`

Thanks.

Comment: You could just return `indexOf` Sprice. Then iterate backwards, until you get the first square bracket, likewise for the last and then cut the string at those indexes?

Comment: Hi @SeanT How can I use indexOf to return array I want ?

Comment: Try [`/\[([^[\]]*SPrice[^[\]]*)]/.exec(s)[0]`](https://regex101.com/r/56X7eo/1) (or `[1]`, not sure what you need)

Comment: Can you please update to answer? I will check and give the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\[[^[\]]*SPrice[^[\]]*]/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/56X7eo/1)

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^[\]]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `SPrice` - a `SPrice` substring
- `[^[\]]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

JS Demo:

```js
var rx = /\[[^[\]]*SPrice[^[\]]*]/g;
var str = "I have two square brackets are [Apple = Red, Cool, Sweet] and [Check+SPrice = Cheap, Expensive, Comfortable]";
console.log(str.match(rx));
```